# Writing to DB using EF6 in async process randomly yielding "property 'Id' is part of object's key ..."

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I have a base class called ServicePluginBase that implements logging.

```
public class PluginLog 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}

public class SQLPluginLogger : IPluginLogger
{
    //EFLogginContext maps PluginLog like so:
    // modelBuilder.Entity<PluginLog>().ToTable("log").HasKey(l => l.Id)
    private EFLoggingContext _logger = new EFLoggingContext();

    public IQueryable<PluginLog> LogItems 
    {
       get { return _logger.LogItems; }
    }

    public void LogEvent(PluginLog item)
    {
        _logger.LogItems.Add(item);
        _logger.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public abstract class ServicePluginBase : IPlugin
{
   private IPluginLogger _logger;

   public ServicePluginBase(IPluginLogger logger)
   {
       _logger = logger;
   }

   protected LogEvent(string eventName, string details)
   {
       PluginLog _event = new PluginLog()
       {
           ServiceId = this.Id,
           Event = eventName,
           Details = details,
           User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name,
           DateTime = DateTime.Now
        };
        _logger.LogEvent(_event);
    }
}
```

Now, within my concrete class, I log events as they happen.  In one class, I have some asynchronous methods running -- and logging.  Sometimes this works great.  Other times, **I get the error stating that "Property 'Id' is part of the object's key and cannot be updated."**  Interestingly enough, I have absolutely no code that updates the value of Id and I never do Updates of log entries -- I only Add new ones.

Here is the async code from one of my plugins.

```
public class CPTManager : ServicePluginBase
{
    public override async Task HandlePluginProcessAsync()
    {
        ...
        await ProcessUsersAsync(requiredUsersList, currentUsersList);
    }

    private async Task ProcessUsersAsync(List<ExtendedUser> required, List<ExtendedUser> current)
    {
        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            var removals = currentUsers.Where(cu => !required.Select(r => r.id).Contains(cu.id)).ToList();
            await DisableUsersAsync(removals http);

            await AddRequiredUsersAsync(requiredUsers.Where(ru => ru.MustAdd).ToList());
        }
    }

    private async Task DisableUsersAsync(List<ExtendedUser> users, HttpClient client)
    {
        LogEvent("Disable Users","Total to disable: " + users.Count());
        await Task.WhenAll(users.Select(async user => 
        {
           ...  //Http call to disable user via Web API
           string status = "Disable User";
           if(response.status == "ERROR")
           {
               EmailFailDisableNotification(user);
               status += " - Fail";
           }
           LogEvent(statusText, ...);

           if(response.status != "ERROR")
           {
              //Update FoxPro database via OleDbConnection (not EF)
              LogEvent("ClearUDF", ...);
           }
         }));
    }

    private async Task AddRequiredUsersAsync(List<ExtendedUser> users, HttpClient client)
    {
        LogEvent("Add Required Users", "Total users to add: " + users.Count());
        await Task.WhenAll(users.Select(async user =>
        {
            ...  //Http call to add user via web API
            LogEvent("Add User", ...);

            if(response.status != "ERROR")
            {
                 //Update FoxPro DB via OleDBConnection (not EF)
                 LogEvent("UDF UPdate",...);
            }
        }));

    }
}
```

First, I'm confused why I'm getting the error mentioned above -- "Id can't be updated" ... I'm not populating the Id field nor am I doing updates to the Log file.  There are no related tables -- just the single log table.

My guess is that I'm doing something improperly in regards to asynchronous processing, but I'm having trouble seeing it if I am.

Any ideas as to what may be going on?

Comment: What do you mean "I'm confused why I'm being told that Id can't be updated". Are you receiving an exception?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I buried the line about the error in the middle of the post.  I've bolded it so it stands out a bit more.

Comment: If that is an exception, give the full stacktrace and exception class name.

Comment: I am trying to get a stacktrace for you.  Like I said, this happens randomly so I'm having trouble getting it to occur again.

Comment: How many threads can access the context object?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with threading.  As far as I'm aware, I'm not multi-threading at all -- meaning that only a single thread has access.  However, if `Task.WhenAll()` creates concurrent threads, then many threads would have access via the `LogEvent()` method.

Comment: Are you instantiating a new CPTManager for each service call? Are you instantiating a new Logger for each CPTManager? Your answer should be yes to both questions.

Comment: Yes to both.  `var service = new CPTManager(new SQLPluginLogger());`